# 2 equations with 2 unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equations:

$\hat{L}=\lambda_{L1}\hat{y}_1+\lambda_{L2}\hat{y}_2 $

$0=\lambda_{K1}\hat{y}_1+\lambda_{K2}\hat{y}_2 $

I should show that:

$\hat{y}_1=\frac{\lambda_{K2}}{\lambda_{K2}-\lambda_{L2}}\hat{L}$

$\hat{y}_2=\frac{\lambda_{K1}}{\lambda_{K1}-\lambda_{L1}}\hat{L}$

But how do I do that when I have this two equations?

Comment: should the $$y$$ not $$y_2$$?

Comment: Yes, of couse. My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the second equation we get:
$$-\lambda_{k_1}y_1=\lambda_{k_2}y_2$$ from here we get
$$y_1=\frac{-\lambda_{k_2}}{\lambda_{k_1}}y_2$$ thus we have
with the first equation
$$L=\left(-\frac{\lambda_{k_2}\lambda_{L_1}}{\lambda_{k_1}}+\lambda_{L_2}\right)y_2$$
from here we get after simplification:
$$y_2=\frac{L\lambda_{k_1}}{\lambda_{L_2}\lambda_{k_1}-\lambda_{L_1}\lambda_{k_2}}$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. Btw I think you have written $L_{L1}$ instead of $\lambda_{L_1}$ in the third equation.